# Shiny data table does not render with RStudio server and shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have this simple app, and it won't render the shiny data table when run from RStudio server / Shiny Server, but works just fine when run on desktop RStudio with Shiny:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput('table1'),
  plotOutput('plot1')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mtcars)
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I type just `datatable(mtcars)` in the RStudio server console, I do get the data table output perfectly fine in the viewer. Just when I run this as a Shiny app, I am having a problem. Any thoughts on what might cause this?

```
packageVersion('DT')
[1] ‘0.1.56’
packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘0.13.2’
version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu     
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.0                         
year           2016                        
month          05                          
day            03                          
svn rev        70573                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

Comment: Is this a potential web browser issue? Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Tried IE and Chrome....

Comment: This might be related? https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/306

Comment: Is there a way to tell what specific version of 'dev' version I am at? For example, I have version .56 in my desktop version of R, and there, it works fine (the exact same code). The one that is not working, I just installed today. So, it must have had other checkins.

Comment: You can use `devtools::session_info()` to find out which specific commit that you are at. You can then find the specific commit here https://github.com/rstudio/DT/commits/master. Furthermore, `devtools::install_github` allows you to specify a commit number via `ref` parameter

Comment: Downgraded to DT on CRAN at the expense of new functionality. Things working lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A comma is missing here:

```
dataTableOutput('table1'),
```

Comment: No, that is not my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Shiny has its [own](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/tableOutput.html) renderDataTable, dataTableOutput, and dataTable functions. You could

1. try to remove the DT library, so there is no confusion whether the Shiny or DT function is called.
2. try to prepend each renderDataTable, dataTableOutput, and dataTable function with DT, which ensures that you always use the DT variant.

E.g.,

```
DT::renderDataTable
```